# Dynamically Generate the JSON Schema from the JSON file in JAVA without using the POJO

Tags: java, json, jsonparser, jpath

Any suggestions for getting the JPATH's for the input JSON file. Basically a tree structure of the JSON schema from the JSON file

Comment: Had a similare use case. I used Map.class, typically
Map<String, Object>

Comment: I do not have an Object to get the schema. Its just the JSON file from which we need to get the schema

Answer (score 0):

You should be okay to use `JsonParser` this way;

First, get the JSON file content as a String. (Say `jsonString`)

Then code something like this;

```
JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
JsonObject o = parser.parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
```

Once you have the JSON Object, you can use the [JsonPath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to get what you may need.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try https://github.com/saasquatch/json-schema-inferrer

Json file or string to JsonNode, then

```
JsonSchemaInferrer.newBuilder()
  .setSpecVersion(SpecVersion.DRAFT_06).build()
  .inferForSample(jsonNode)
```